# How to make freestyle lines stay the same size?

Tags: freestyle

Is it possible to make freestyle lines stay the same width relative to the distance from the camera?

The way free style lines behave by default, they stay the same width in pixels, but vary relative to the size of rendered objects.

How can I make freestyle lines appear small when rendered on objects far away (as the object appears small) and large on objects close to the camera? (as nearby objects appear large)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. **Here is how:**

First change the *Line Thickness* parameter under Properties tab > Freestyle to *Relative* **(1)**

[image]

Next go to the Render layers properties, or just click the icon in the Freestyle panel **(2)**. Then go to the thickness tab **(3)**, and then Add a *Distance from Camera* modifier **(4)** .
You then have to check the *invert* box **(5)** to that the lines decrease in width over the distance. You will see a parameter slider box called *Range Max* **(6)** , this value should be the distance of the farthest object away visible in the shot.You can use the *Fill Range by selection*, or do it manually. In my case the object is about 100BU away. *Value Min* **(7)** and *Value Max* **(8)**  control the ending width and starting width, respectively.

[image]

---

**Note:**

- For animations you might have to set keyframes for these values
- You can ignore the *Base Thickness* parameter
- The *Distance from Object* modifier can achieve similar results and may be more suitable for animations.
- Lines are drawn based on edges. One long cube is only going to have the same width through, regardless of the modifier.

[image]

---

**Final Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you go to the *Freestyle Line Style* panel, go to *Thickness* and add a *Distance from Camera modifier*. It seems like a good idea to select all objects in your scene and press *Fill Range by Selection*, so the range matches your scene. *Value min* and *Value max* are basically how thin or thick your lines can get. Also tick *Invert* else objects far away will get a thicker line.

[image: Freestyle Line Style panel]