# How to keep the details and line thickness in freestyle despite the movement of the camera?

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to do a project with freestyle cartoon style.
I have two characters, one large and one small, both quite detailed. When I render separately I have no problem, but when I put the two together the small loses much of its details. Freestyle lines become too thick to the model and lose a lot of detail. The problem, I think, is bring in / out the camera to frame the two characters in the picture.
Is there any way around this?
Thanks

Example:

[image: Smal Character]

[image: Big and Small character]

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/how-to-make-freestyle-lines-stay-the-same-size/3533#3533

Comment: See the link Ray Mairlot posted, but use Distance from Object instead of Distance from Camera. You'll need to make an Empty or something to serve as the object that will anchor the size.